# Do flybacks need an ac input?

Tags: transformer, high-voltage, high-frequency, flyback

I just bought a flyback transformer, or rather, a *high voltage generator*, and it says it takes 3v dc but is that possible?

Comment: It's probably a transformer connected to an oscillator circuit which operates from DC. Without a datasheet (or at least a photo) it's hard to be 100% sure. Transformers (most of them you'll likely run into, anyway) only work on AC.

Comment: @EmmettP  Please post this question to Amazon.  EE.SE isn't Amazon's volunteer application support.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you bought a high voltage generator like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JVJDEZE), which contains both a transformer and an oscillator to drive it. If this is the case, you will only need to input the required voltage. (In your case this is 3v dc, which you can obtain from two AA batteries in [series](https://itp.nyu.edu/archive/physcomp-spring2014/uploads/battery_series.jpg)) If you have a [flyback transformer](http://www.electronicrepairguide.com/images/flyback1.jpg), you will need your own driving circuitry. [This page](http://uzzors2k.4hv.org/index.php?page=flybacktransformerdrivers) has many possible circuits you could use.

Comment: That's the exact one I bought

Comment: @EmmettP Then you will need to use an input voltage 3 to 6 volts dc, as the posting states.